# Fastest way to use Vision API on 10,000+ images with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I can't seem to find a method in python that can compete with say DarkNet in terms of speed. One would think there'd be inbuilt network processing of images. What i'm currently doing is this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from google.cloud import vision, firestore


def detect_faces_uri(uri):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = vision.types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.face_detection(image=image)
    faces = response.face_annotations

    if faces:
        print('found face!')
        return uri

list_of_uris = ['gs://example/image.png'*...] # * 10,000+

detected_images = Parallel(n_jobs=12)(delayed(detect_faces_uri)(url) for url in tqdm(list_of_uris))
```

I'm processing about 4 - 10 at a time, surely I can get this to go faster?

Comment: Parallel + Async would be the fastest way to make multiple API calls in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing more in parallel would get it done faster. You can also include more than 1 image in a [single annotate request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate). For python see the [batch_annotate_images](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/vision/google/cloud/vision_v1/gapic/image_annotator_client.py#L190) method.

[This](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/index.html#example-usage) has an example of what a single request looks like. You would use an array of requests with batch_annotate_images.

If you just want to send the requests into the api fast and retrieve the results sometime later, you could use [asyncBatchAnnotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/asyncBatchAnnotate).

Comment: Could you give me an example for the multiple images in one request, its just not making sense to me. is my paths were `gs://somebucket/img1.png, gs://somebucket/img2.png, gs://somebucket/img3.png` what would that look like?